# OpenCV AttributeError module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Tracker_create'

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried to run this code but get an Attribute Error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import cv2
    import sys
     
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use
 
    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'CSRT', 'MOSSE']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[5]
 
    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'CSRT':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
 
    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture("./videos/chaplin.mp4")
 
    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()
 
    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()
     
    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)
 
    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
 
    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
 
    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
         
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()
 
        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
 
        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
 
        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
 
        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
     
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);
 
        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)
 
        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jatin\OpenCV-Object-Tracking\index.py", line 15, in <module>
    tracker = cv2.cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Tracker_create'
```

Comment: Your code has `cv2.cv2.Tracker_create` --- there should only be one `cv2`. Does that solve your problem? Also, when you are trying to debug something from a tutorial, you should link where you got the code.

Comment: @alkasm One `cv2` doesn't worked, It gives same error.

Comment: Some modules are moved to `legacy` in [this commit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/80c197590ccfbd1dd9b4f54b250d26e06e840683#diff-464b73bada27b778378fe977d4977a7d7518572eb708ddaba8dc0ad4b241c489).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends on which packages of OpenCV and the version you have installed.

I believe you need **OpenCV 3.4+** to run those models. Some tracker models are available in 3.2, and 3.3. All trackers in your script are available in 3.4

OpenCV packages:
`opencv-python`: This repository contains the main modules of the OpenCV library.

`opencv-contrib-python`: The opencv-contrib-python repository contains both the main modules along with the contrib modules

`python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python`, check to see if you have 3.4+, with `pip show opencv` .

See [how to install opencv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) for more details

## Updates

As @user48956 pointed out `opencv v 4.5.x` has moved some of these algorithms to `cv2.legacy`. For example, to access `TrackerMOSSE_create` function. You would have to get it from`cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create`.

I would recommend keeping up with opencv [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aopencv+legacy&type=code) as some functions/algorithms will likely move around or be deleted.

Comment: At least for:
opencv-python==4.5.2.52, opencv-python==4.5.2.52   ... -->
cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create is missing

Comment: Have you tried  `pip install opencv-contrib-python`? The `contrib` has more features. I have not check `4.5.X`  yet.

Comment: Yes, and with the same version. It is moved to cv2.legacy for some reason I reason. I added a new answer.

Comment: Should we not update this answer to include that?

Comment: In openCV 4.5.5 doesn't exist, cv2.legacy, exist some Trackers but not others like CSRT doesn't show up but DaSiamRPN is available

Answer (score 6):

If you are using OpenCV 4 or above then the above code may not work.

> `if int(minor_ver) < 3:` line breaks for OpenCV 4
>
> You need to install just opencv contrib for this experiment

#### My Virtual Env contains

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

requirements.txt

```
dlib==19.19.0
imutils==0.5.3
numpy==1.18.4
opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34
scipy==1.4.1
```

#### modified code, compatible with OpenCV 4 version

tracker.py

```py
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
print(cv2.__version__)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use

    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'CSRT', 'MOSSE']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[6]

    if int(major_ver) < 4 and int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'CSRT':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()

    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break

        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

Comment: For some reason, the latest opencv-contrib-python version (4.5.1.48) at the time of writing did not work for me. But the version (4.2.0.34) used here works, thanks.

Comment: Same here:
opencv-python==4.5.2.52, opencv-python==4.5.2.52   ... -->
cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create is missing

Answer (score 4):

I was getting an error with:
`tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE.create()`

even thought I had already installed:
opencv-contrib-python

I was able to fix the error by using this instead:
`tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerMOSSE.create()`

Answer (score 4):

For at least for:

- opencv-contrib-python==4.5.2.52

you need to replace:

```
cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
```

with...

```
cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
```

Answer (score 2):

My version of Python is 3.7, which doesn't seem to ignore the code below.

```
if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
```

I simply deleted it and the module runs.

---

An unrelated but hopefully helpful suggestion.  At the end of the code above, I added a `destroyAllWindows() command, which cleans up the viewer:

```
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: I think you are using IDLE. At the end of the program, the window is closed automatically. IDLE is still interactive after reaching the end of the script.

Comment: I was using Spyder.  Is that similar to IDLE in this regard?

Comment: I tested with Jupyter Notebook. They all are the same in the sense that `python` still keeps running. Yours is a good advise, I just wanted to note the reason behind.

Answer (score 2):

Just install the following.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

here by using csrt tracker.

```
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_path")
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
ret, frame = cap.read()
bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
tracker.init(frame, bbox)

while True:   
    frame_id = 0 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    success, bbox = tracker.update(frame)    
    if success:
        x, y, w, h = [int(i) for i in bbox]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)    
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```