# Want to detect single object like a tennis ball from the video file. AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerBoosting_create'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Here is my code for the project that I am developing

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import cv2
from random import randint
import imutils
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import *

v = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/innvonix/PycharmProjects/nsrk2/tennisv.mp4") # video

trackerTypes = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL', 'KCF','TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']

def createTrackerByName(trackerType):
  # Create a tracker based on tracker name
  if trackerType == trackerTypes[0]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[1]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[2]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[3]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[4]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[5]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[6]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
  elif trackerType == trackerTypes[7]:
    tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
  else:
    tracker = None
    print('Incorrect tracker name')
    print('Available trackers are:')
    for t in trackerTypes:
      print(t)



  return tracker

ret, frame = v.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=600)
cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
bb = cv2.selectROI('Frame',frame)
tracker.init(frame,bb)
```

Here is the error that i am getting using the above code:

> ```
> 'boosting' : cv2.TrackerBoosting_create, AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerBoosting_create'
> ```
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks in advance please help me with this friends...

Comment: According to another questions answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922153/opencv-attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-tracker-create
Your openCV version should be important, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

For at least for:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.2.52
```

you need to replace:

```
cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
```

with...

```
cv2.legacy.cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
```

For more details check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df1/classcv_1_1legacy_1_1TrackerBoosting.html)

Comment: You have shown it only for one tracker. Can you show the same for the other trackers as well? like GOTURN, MedianFlow, TLD, KCF, etc.?